# Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I get an error after updating from my last project. Not a problem in my code but I'm having trouble with build.gradle. How can I fix it?

build.gradle code here:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.xxx.axxx'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 6
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/asmack-android-8-4.0.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'
}
```

Gradle Sync message output:

```
Error:(27, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
**Possible causes:
The project 'Atomic4Mobile' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
**Gradle settings**
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
**Apply Gradle plugin**
```

Comment: Try `minifyEnabled` instead of `runProguard`.

Comment: I still cannot believe this got so many upvotes. Stay up to date with the changes here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system.

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 821):

[image]If you are using version 0.14.0 or higher of the gradle plugin, you should replace *"runProguard"* with *"minifyEnabled"* in your build.gradle files.

*runProguard* was renamed to *minifyEnabled* in version 0.14.0. For more info, [See Android Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Comment: The source for this is [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0).

Comment: there are two build.gradle files, the inner one , the one in the app subdirectory, is the one.

Comment: Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'classpath()'
Possible causes: The project 'Sample' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Answer (score 281):

Using `'minifyEnabled'` instead of `'runProguard'` works properly.

**`Previous code:`**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

**`Current code:`**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 72):

If you are migrating to 1.0.0 you need to change the following properties.

In the Project's *build.gradle* file you need to replace minifyEnabled.

Hence your new build type should be

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'        
    }
}
```

Also make sure that gradle version is 1.0.0 like

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

in the *build.gradle* file.

This should solve the problem.

Source:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Answer (score 17):

By changing **runProguard** to **minifyEnabled**, part of the issue gets fixed.

But the fix can cause "Library Projects cannot set application Id" (you can find the fix for this here **[Android Studio 1.0 and error "Library projects cannot set applicationId"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374933/android-studio-1-0-and-error-library-projects-cannot-set-applicationid)**).

By removing application Id in the build.gradle file, you should be good to go.

Comment: Try to trace the answer here and then give the link to it.

Comment: Somebody should have told that already. Great! After doing **minifyEnabled**, need to do this as well in buld.gradle of all the external library projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

**runProguard** has been renamed to **minifyEnabled** in version 0.14.0 (2014/10/31) or more in Gradle.

To fix this, you need to change runProguard to minifyEnabled in the **build.gradle** file of your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is for [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
buildTypes {
    getByName("release") { // or simply  release {  in newer versions of Android Gradle Plugin (AGP)
      isMinifyEnabled = true
      isShrinkResources = true
      proguardFiles(
        // "proguard-android-optimize.txt" reduces size more than "proguard-android.txt"
        getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
        "proguard-rules.pro"
      )
      signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("mySigningConfig")
    }
}
```

I'm using Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version 7 in my top-level build file:

```kotlin
buildscript {
  // ...
  dependencies {
      classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
      // ...
  }
}
```