# android studio - problems with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I making a code maintenance in of android app that someone else writed in android studio.

when i try to sync project with Gradle files, i get this error message:

```
23:46:27 UnsupportedMethodException
     Failed to set up Android modules in project 'BuyTheWay': Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories().
     The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
     To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
     Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.
```

I am using the 0.8.14 version of android studio.

In a anser to a similar queshtion [Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078075/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard) , it was recommended to replace in the build.gradle file (**in the app folder**) the line:

```
runProguard false
```

with

```
minifyEnabled false
```

but it dosent help for me, because the compiler also marks "getDefaultProguardFile" in the line

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
```

and clains that:

```
cannot resolve symbol getDefaultProguardFile
```

trying a diffrent approach, and changing the build.grale **in the gragle folder**, dint help

this is the original code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

when i change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
```

with

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
```

and try to sync project with Gradle files, i get this error message:

```
    Error:(17, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:
     The project 'BuyTheWay' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
    <a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a>
    The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
    <a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

One step can solve this problem.

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    runProguard false // <==== **remove this line**
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
}
```

Comment: For Android Studio, it was this .. apply plugin: 'idea'   .  Thanks