# Error when upgrading Android Studio project from 0.8.6 to RC4

Tags: android

I have been using Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.6 for my current project.  Recently, I downloaded the newest version of Android Studio (RC4).  After installing version RC4, I loaded my project from "existing Android Studio project".  While opening the 0.8.6 based project, I get the error "The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2).  The recommended version is 1.0.0-rc4."  I then clicked on the "Fix plugin version and re-import project" link and I get an error saying the it is unable to find references Android Gradle plug-in in build.gradle files.  Will someone explain to me exactly what I need to do to get the newer version of Android Studio working with the older project.  If I can't can't this Gradle thing figured out, I will have to go back to Eclipse.  Thanks.

Comment: Step #1: Find the `build.gradle` file(s) in your project. Step #2: Find the subset of those that load the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` dependency in the `buildscript` closure. Step #3: Set the version number to `1.0.0-rc4`, so you wind up with: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'`.

Comment: In the main project, I changed the build:gradle to 1.0.0-rc4.  I closed Android Studio and then reopened it.  For one of the linked projects, I get an error message "Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'.  How do I eliminate this error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Step #1: Find the build.gradle file(s) in your project.

Step #2: Find the subset of those that load the com.android.tools.build:gradle dependency in the buildscript closure.

Step #3: Set the version number to 1.0.0-rc4, so you wind up with: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'.

> For one of the linked projects, I get an error message "Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'. How do I eliminate this error?

Replace `runProguard` with `minifyEnabled`, as is covered in [the release notes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) for the 0.14.0 edition of the plugin, plus many Stack Overflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078075/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have all issues resolved now!

Comment: Hi.I have same issue, but when i follow these steps, i got another error: -_"Cause:org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling"_ Any ideas how to fix new one?

Comment: @Sergii: I recommend that you open a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you post your Gradle build files and the complete stack trace that Gradle is generating.