# org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am still using Android Studio 0.8.9 on my Macbook Air. On my iMac i installed Android Studio 1.0.

As 1.0 only supports 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0' i had to change my build.gradles 
as mentioned here. [Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078075/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard)

0.8.9 uses 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example...."
         minSdkVersion 19
         targetSdkVersion 20
         versionCode 1
         versionName "0.87"
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
    }
    packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    dexOptions {
         preDexLibraries = false
    } }

repositories {
     mavenCentral()
     flatDir {
     dirs 'libs'
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
     compile 'com.spotify.sdk:spotifysdk:1.0.0-beta6@aar'
     compile('se.michaelthelin.spotify:spotify-web-api-java:1.4.20') 
}
```

With the 0.8.9 beta on my MacBook Air my App builds fine. On my iMac i get this error.

org.apache.commons.collections.ArrayStack has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.

**UPDATE**
The problems seems to be that commons-collections is added to the external libraries and commons-beanutils which also includes a commons-collections.

compile('se.michaelthelin.spotify:spotify-web-api-java:1.4.20') {
        exclude group: "commons-beanutils", module: "commons-beanutils"
    }

if i exclude the commons-beanutils the build process is fine, but the app crashes, as it needs the commons-beanutils. same if i exclude the commons-collections.

furthermore i tried to manually remove the folder common-collections from the commons-beanutils jar, but this also does not work..

Answer (score 1):

finally it works.

this one does not include commons-collections, so everything works fine.
compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:20030211.134440'

don't understand why this was not necessary in beta 0.8.9

```
compile('se.michaelthelin.spotify:spotify-web-api-java:1.4.20') {
        exclude group: "commons-beanutils", module: "commons-beanutils"

    }
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:20030211.134440'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
project > clean

project > rebuild
```

and run again

Comment: already tried this, project rebuild works, but it throws the same error on run.

Comment: Try to remove all generated directories (build, bin, etc...) and clean & rebuild again.

If this do not work, you have to search which libraries have this class and exclude one.

Comment: Thanks for your help, compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15' is causing the problem. if i remove this (and remove my java-files) it runs without error. the json-lib also has org.apache.commons.collections, see at  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib/2.4. So how do i exlude it in build.gradle?

Comment: this works but now my app is crashing on runtime. :-(          compile ('net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15')
            {
                exclude group: "commons-collections", module: "commons-collections"
            }