# Gradle DSL Method not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I installed the latest version of Android Studio, and imported an older project. I get this error when I try to open it:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078075/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard)

Answer (score 2):

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system - 0.14.0 (2014/10/31)

Google renamed it to minifyEnabled, look for it in the build.gradle file and substitute accordingly