# How can i import this android library to my project?

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

https://github.com/keithellistemp/MaterialWidget

i need this layout to my project 
but there are no dependency and import option in this git

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a Library Project to a android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248196/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-a-android-project)

Answer (score 1):

You can download it in a **zip** format and then add it in your **libs** folder in the application.

Comment: Error:(28, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes: The project 'MaterialWidget' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Comment: If you are using version 0.14.0 or higher of the gradle plugin, you should replace "runProguard" with "minifyEnabled" in your build.gradle files.
runProguard was renamed to minifyEnabled in version 0.14.0. For more info,[link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

Comment: Using 'minifyEnabled' instead of 'runProguard' works properly.

Comment: buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

Comment: minifyEnabled true is the thing i should do

Answer (score 0):

Either through Gradle, or pull the source yourself and copy it to your project.

Comment: Error:(28, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:The project 'MaterialWidget' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Comment: This is a different issue altogether: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078075/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard