# Project at compile time, Gradle appeared some errors, there are no similar problems encountered

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project at run time, there was a gradle version of the error, I tried a lot of ways are not resolved, we have not encountered a similar error, the following is the error log.

> Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'apply()' Possible
>   causes:The project 'xindatx1.6.0' may be using a version of the
>   Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g.
>   'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0). Fix plugin version and sync
>   projectThe project 'xindatx1.6.0' may be using a version of Gradle
>   that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper fileThe build
>   file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: what you have tried

Comment: post your build graddle code

Comment: Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'apply()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'xindatx1.6.0' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix plugin version and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'xindatx1.6.0' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: We have no effect to re construct gradle

Comment: try this answer on... http://stackoverflow.com/a/27266373/3678308

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
       classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.1'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.2' // add plugin
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```