# How to fix > No signature of method: build_dxc6m5s863o0nfrfjdg2bqjp.android() is applicable for argument types

Tags: android

Problem: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_dxc6m5s863o0nfrfjdg2bqjp.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_dxc6m5s863o0nfrfjdg2bqjp$_run_closure1) values: [build_dxc6m5s863o0nfrfjdg2bqjp$_run_closure1@18112963]

Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.numix.calculator_pro"

        testApplicationId "com.numix.calculator_pro_pro.pro.tests"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/achartengine.jar')
    compile files('libs/ejml-0.21.jar')
    compile files('libs/arity-2.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/slider.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0-javadoc.jar')
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266373/5914345

Answer (score 2):

Check that versionCode variable exists in build.gradle and it's integer, not string:

```
defaultConfig {
    //....
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.15"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **runProguard** with **minifyEnabled**

From:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
```

to:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
```