# No signature of method: build_9oqkz1yq0b57t4arqvsiar91y.android() is applicable for argument types:

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add firestore to my note app to store my notes and when I run it this error comes:

```
Build file '~/StudioProjects/noteapp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 29

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_9oqkz1yq0b57t4arqvsiar91y.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_9oqkz1yq0b57t4arqvsiar91y$_run_closure2) values: [build_9oqkz1yq0b57t4arqvsiar91y$_run_closure2@2d8103c5]
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.noteapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            useProGaurd false
            shrinkResources false
            
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

How do I solve this? Tell me if you need my main.dart as well.

**EDIT:** It got solved by this:
[Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266373/9722336)

Comment: Did you try cleaning the build and rebuilding?

Comment: @gtxtreme yes i did

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266373/9722336

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix ERROR: No signature of method: build\_ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma.android()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807520/how-to-fix-error-no-signature-of-method-build-ap86oam3dut3pxce3x49rdtma-androi)

Comment: @LalitFauzdar I tried it, and it didn't work because I didn't have the experimental functions

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove this line from my build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            //useProGaurd false
            shrinkResources false
            
        }
    }
```

Useprogaurd:false

I got the idea from this and from @gtxtreme:
[Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266373/9722336)

Comment: It's weird that this error exist, but nevertheless, Cheers! Happy Coding