# Gradle DSL method not found: android()

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Any suggestions to fix this problem:
I am getting this error in android studio after importing Project

Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
Possible causes:

The project 'LoginActivity' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

There is a bar notification which says: Gradle project sync failed. Basic fuctionality (eg: editing, debugging) will not work properly.

Please help me to get rid of this problem. Thanks!

Comment: For me the response that solved the problem was other. Check this Out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409384/android-studio-build-script-error-unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-andro?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

If you have an `android` block in your build script, you need one of the following two statements, depending on whether your module is an application module or a library module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

or:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Having said that, there are other problems with your build script. For one, this is a top-level build script (as you can see by the comment that says "Top-level build file where you can add configuration options..."), so it's likely that there isn't actually a top-level module for the `android` block to apply to, so adding the `apply plugin` statement may just lead to a different error. If that happens, remove the `android` block.

Another issue is that you already have a `apply plugin: 'java'` statement in this build script. You can't use both the Java and the Android plugins in the same build script; they collide with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete this method from your root build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.0.0'
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
} }
```

It should work after you compile again.

Answer (score 0):

if get error then check your gradle file version and remove other gradle dependancy like `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'`  it may solve the problem