# How to fix the gradle error?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

My project includes `NDK` . And this is the `build.gradle` file (app-level).

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 25
        buildToolsVersion = "25.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
        }
    }
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "HelloARVideoNative"
        cppFlags.add("-I${file("/home/obx/Downloads/EasyARSDKSamples/package/include")}".toString())
        cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-frtti")
        stl = "gnustl_static"
        ldLibs.add("log")
        ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.with {
                abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
        }
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                    library file("/home/obx/Downloads/EasyARSDKSamples/package/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libEasyAR.so") abi "armeabi-v7a"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '/home/obx/Downloads/EasyARSDKSamples/package/Android/libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the error that I do obtain :

> Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'library()'

This is what I tried :

- [Getting Error “Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'” when Syncing Build.Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156428/getting-error-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile-when-syncing-build-grad)
- [Gradle DSL method not found: android()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909842/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android)
- [Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'ependencies()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401231/gradle-sync-failed-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-ependencies)

This is my top level `gradle` file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Question:** What is possibly causing this; and how to resolve ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps but http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental says that at some point Android Gradle syntax for NDK libraries was changed

> The DSL for specifying dependencies on a specific library files have changed to follow Gradle's native dependency DSL.

From their examlpe it looks like you need to change your script to be something like

```
model {
    ...
    repositories {
        prebuilt(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryFile = file("/home/obx/Downloads/EasyARSDKSamples/package/Android/libs/armeabi-v7a/libEasyAR.so")
                // or even 
                // sharedLibraryFile = file("/home/obx/Downloads/EasyARSDKSamples/package/Android/libs/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libEasyAR.so")
            }
        }
    }
    android.sources {
        main {
            jni {
                dependencies {
                     library "prebuilt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may aslo consider using `jniLibs` instead of `jni` which is described as

> You can add native dependency to either 'jniLibs' or 'jni' source set.  When dependency is added to "jniLibs" the native library will be package into the application/library, but it will not be used for compiling the JNI code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try :)

Comment: @OBX, let us know if this was actually the issue or is it something else

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it, it was a problem with the linkage of `libEasyAR.so`.
This is how my `build.gradle` look like after some modifications :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

    model {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion = 25
            buildToolsVersion = "25.0.2"

            defaultConfig.with {
                applicationId = "cn.easyar.samples.helloar"
                minSdkVersion.apiLevel  =15
                targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
                versionCode = 1
                versionName = "1.0"
            }
        }
        android.buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }
        android.ndk {
            moduleName = "HelloARNative"
            cppFlags.add("-I${file("../../../package/include")}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            cppFlags.add("-frtti")
            stl = "gnustl_static"
            ldFlags.add("-LC:/Users/Me/Documents/AR_SDK/EasyAR/EasyARSDKSamples/Android/HelloARNative/app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a")
            ldLibs.add("log")
            ldLibs.add("GLESv2")
            ldLibs.add("EasyAR")
        }
        android.productFlavors {
            create("arm") {
                ndk.with {
                    abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
                }
            }
        }
        repositories {
            libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
                prebuilt {
                    headers.srcDir "src/main/jni"
                    binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                        sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/libEasyAR.so")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        android.sources {
            main {
                jniLibs {
                    dependencies {
                        library "prebuilt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../../../package/Android/libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    }
```

You have to add the library in a folder `libs` under your folder `main`.

Hope that it will help !

(Sorry for my english, I'm a french guy)